# Maven plugins in eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

In some new eclipse versions it shows that some maven plugins are no longer available on marketplace. Concrete
jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.3:xjc
maven-deploy-support-plugin:1.4.106:deploy
What does this mean? I know there use to be more than one Maven plugins to eclipse and usually maven worked in eclipse pretty bad, because plugins didn't covered all of functionality of maven. 
In new eclipse like Mars there is some Maven integration from the start, you don't need to install any third-party plugin. So I guess this plugins could be probably ignored but I'm not sure. Am I right?